# Probability Distribution of a Coherent Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, coherent-states

I'm currently reading Quantum Optics by Scully and Zubairy and come across a derivation in which I am stuck as to what to do next.

Starting with a general solution to the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian:
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial t} = \left(-\frac{\hbar}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial q^2}+\frac{\nu^2q^2}{2}\right)\psi,\qquad \psi(q,t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\phi_n(q)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}.$$

Where $\phi_n(q)$ is the coordinate representations of the oscillator number state $|{n}\rangle$.

$\phi_n$ are orthonormal, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi_n^*\phi_mdq=\delta_{nm}.$

Also given is the initial wavefunction at time $t = 0$:

$$\psi(q,0) = \left(\frac{\nu}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{1/4}\exp\left[\frac{-\nu}{2\hbar}(q-q_0)^2\right].$$

Where $q_0>0$ is the initial displacement of the particle in the oscillator potential centred at $q=0$.

I want to find the coefficients $a_n$, so considering the expansion of $\psi$ at $t=0$ leads to the following equality:

$$\psi(q,0) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\phi_n(q) = \left(\frac{\nu}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{1/4}\exp\left[\frac{-\nu}{2\hbar}(q-q_0)^2\right].$$

Then multiplying by $\phi_m^*$, integrating over all of $q$ and using the orthonormality property leads to:

$$a_m = \left(\frac{\nu}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{1/4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi_m^*(q)\exp\left[\frac{-\nu}{2\hbar}(q-q_0)^2\right]dq.$$

It is here I am at a loss as what to do to simplify this integral as I want to calculate the probability density at any future time $t$. I have considered using the definition of $\phi_n$:

$$\phi_n(q)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^nn!}}H_n\left(\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\hbar}}\,q\right)\!\phi_0(q),\qquad 
\phi_0(q) = \left(\frac{\nu}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{1/4} 
\exp\left(\!-\frac{\nu q^2}{2\hbar}\right).$$

With $H_n$ the Hermite polynomials, but this leads to an even more complex integral.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: Your integral doesn't look that bad to me. It nearly has the form of the Hermite polynomials orthogonality relation of $H_n$ with $H_0$, so you just need to massage it fully into that form. I would look for some sort of formula $H_n(x+y) = \sum_{i,j < n} a_{ij}H_i(x)H_j(y)$, and then you should be set

Comment: Thankyou very much for the comment - I will try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notice that $\psi(q)$ corresponds to the spatial translation of the vacuum state:
$$
\psi(q) = \phi_0(q-q_0) = e^{-q_0\frac{d}{dq}}\phi_0(q).
$$
It is convenient to use creation and annihilation operators in further computations:
$$
\hat{a}^+ = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2\nu}}\left(\frac{\nu}{\hbar}q-\frac{d}{dq}\right),\quad
\hat{a}^- = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2\nu}}\left(\frac{\nu}{\hbar}q+\frac{d}{dq}\right).
$$
These operators possess the following remarkable properties:
$$
[\hat{a}^-,\hat{a}^+] = 1,\quad \hat{a}^-\phi_0(q) = 0, \quad
\frac1{\sqrt{n!}}(\hat{a}^+)^n \phi_0(q) = \phi_n(q), \quad
e^{\alpha\hat{a}^+ +  \beta\hat{a}^-} = e^{\alpha\hat{a}^+}e^{\beta\hat{a}^-}e^{\alpha\beta/2}.
$$
Now, it is easy to derive the following chain of equalities:
$$
\psi(q) = \exp\left(\sqrt{\frac{\nu q_0^2}{2\hbar}}(\hat{a}^+ - \hat{a}^-)\right)\phi_0(q) = 
$$
$$
=\exp\left(-\frac{\nu q_0^2}{4\hbar}\right)
\exp\left(\sqrt{\frac{\nu q_0^2}{2\hbar}}\hat{a}^+\right)
\exp\left(-\sqrt{\frac{\nu q_0^2}{2\hbar}}\hat{a}^-\right)\phi_0(q) =
$$
$$
=\exp\left(-\frac{\nu q_0^2}{4\hbar}\right)\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt{n!}}\left(\frac{\nu q_0^2}{2\hbar}\right)^{n/2}\phi_n(q).
$$
From the last equality, you obtain:
$$
a_n = \exp\left(-\frac{\nu q_0^2}{4\hbar}\right) \frac1{\sqrt{n!}}\left(\frac{\nu q_0^2}{2\hbar}\right)^{n/2}.
$$

Update. Equivalent solution without $\hat{a}^\pm$ operators. For the [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials), it is known the generating function:
$$
e^{2xt-t^2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}.
$$
Let's define
$$
t = \frac{q_0}2\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\hbar}},\quad x = q\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\hbar}}
$$
and rewrite $\psi(q)$ in the following manner:
$$
\psi(q) = \left(\frac{\nu}{\pi\hbar}\right)^{1/4} e^{-\nu q^2/2\hbar}e^{\nu qq_0/\hbar}e^{-\nu q^2_0/2\hbar} = \phi_0(q) e^{2xt-t^2} e^{-\nu q^2_0/4\hbar} =
$$
$$
= \phi_0(q) \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n\left(q\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\hbar}}\right)\frac1{n!}\left(\frac{q_0}2\sqrt{\frac{\nu}{\hbar}}\right)^n e^{-\nu q^2_0/4\hbar} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \phi_n(q) \frac1{\sqrt{n!}}\left(\frac{\nu q_0^2}{2\hbar}\right)^{n/2} e^{-\nu q^2_0/4\hbar}.
$$
This representation of $\psi(q)$ coincides with the one obtained earlier and gives the same coefficients $a_n$. This solution also doesn't involve taking integrals. The explicit expression of the [Hermite polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials) is known. I think that direct computation of integrals for $a_n$ is possible but tedious.

Comment: Thanks for the input, greatly appreciated. However this is not the question I was asking - I'm trying to calculate the coefficients for the general solution via the orthonormality of the displaced oscillator eigenfunctions.

Comment: @PolynomialC, my answer gives precisely the $a_n$ coefficients, which you are interested in finding. No? You don't always need to integrate explicitly to find an integral.

Comment: I agree you do not need to integrate explicitly to find the integral - though your method is completely different to the one I have defined above - I am specifically interested in how $a_n$ arise from the method I have detailed above.

Comment: @PolynomialC, I've updated my answer.

Comment: thankyou so much - was just consulting Riley Hobson and Bence and came across this method but was having issues with the hermite expansion of the exponential, brilliant thankyou so much. Both methods I've saved, thanks again!